# Как избавиться от ошибки в Toad for Oracle: "ORA-12541: TNS:нет прослушивателя"?

Tags: oracle

До сегоднешнего дня получалось зайти в Toad for Oracle, все было нормально.

Сегодня же вышла эта ошибка.

Как избавиться от неё? 
Что нужно сделать, чтобы зайти и нормально работать с Toad for Oracle?

Toad for Oracle мне очень сейчас нужен!
Пожалуйста, помогите!

[image: Ошибка:]

Comment: Так запустите прослушку на машине, где стоит БД: `lsnrctl  start`

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: Пойти на машину,  где база стоит,  под юзером,  который эту базу устанавливал, и набрать в окне  cmd.  Потом набрать - tnsping orcl. Если OK, то всё в порядке.

Comment: Вышло следующее: C:\Users\Samsung> tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 24-НОЯ-2016 18:52:39

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Использованы файлы параметров:
D:\app\Samsung\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Использован адаптер TNSNAMES для разрешения псевдонима
Выполнена попытка связи с (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-IF7IKOP)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
TNS-12541: TNS:нет прослушивателя

C:\Users\Samsung>

Comment: Я имел в ввиду -  набрать из первого коммента,  tnsping потом.

Comment: Т.е. сделать сначала "lsnrctl start", потом "tnsping orcl"? Так я сделала. Не помогает. Всё равно пишет, что нет прослушивателя: http://radikal.ru/lfp/s017.radikal.ru/i420/1611/02/03203008df7b.png/htm  .

Comment: Ошибка адаптера -  выложите вывод lsnrctl,  я посмотрю,  а пока перезагрузке машину.

Comment: вывод lsnrctl : http://s014.radikal.ru/i329/1611/73/3eb7c337649d.png

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49059/discussion-between-gadget-and-0xdb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы №2:

Запустить службы Oracle 
( "Управление компьютером" - "Службы" - Запуск служб Oracle)

После этого получилось зайти..

Answer (score 0):

Очень странное решение №1 (хватает только до следующей перезагрузки): 
http://konurbaev-e.blogspot.ru/2013/03/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adapter-error.html